# What does %[^:]: mean in sscanf()?

Tags: c, scanf

What does `%[^:]:` mean in this `sscanf()` statement?

```c
sscanf (buf, "%[^:]:%[^:]:%d:%d:%[^:]:%[^:]:%s\n",
    logname, password, &pw_passwd.pw_uid,
    &pw_passwd.pw_gid, gecos,
    dir, shell);
```

I found out that `%[^\n]` means to scan until `\n` or an enter key. But I can't find the meaning of `%[^:]:`.

Comment: `%[^\n] means scan till \n` Right. Replace `\n` with `:` and you have your answer.

Comment: Read scanf manual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as `%[^\n]` scans until `\n`, `%[^:]` scans until `:`.  So, in this case:

- the 1st `%[^:]` specifier scans until and not including `:`, and puts the extracted value into `logname`
- the following `:` is matched and discarded
- the next `%[^:]` specifier scans until and not including `:`, and puts the extracted value into `password`
- the following `:` is matched and discarded
- the next `%d` specifier scans a number, and puts the extracted value into `pw_passwd.pw_uid`
- the following `:` is matched and discarded
- the next `%d` specifier scans a number, and puts the extracted value into `pw_passwd.pw_gid`
- the following `:` is matched and discarded
- the next `%[^:]` specifier scans until and not including `:`, and puts the extracted value into `gecos`
- the following `:` is matched and discarded
- the next `%[^:]` specifier scans until and not including `:`, and puts the extracted value into `dir`
- the following `:` is matched and discarded
- the next `%s` specifier scans until and not including `\n`, and puts the extracted value into `shell`
- the following `\n` is matched and discarded